# How to validate regex based Resume parser efficiently

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, data-science-model, regex

I am using rule based logic to extract features from resume. Basically I am trying to find if the candidate switched the company in less than 1 year. So I have the code in place to find it using python. However if I want to validate it, I am currently doing it manually for few resumes, meaning I open the resume and find if the candidate switched the company in less than 1 year and compare it with what my regex logic gives. But this is time consuming process to validate.

Is there any better way to validate this piece of python code. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any better way to validate this piece of python code. ?

No, because any automatic method would be equivalent to creating another learner, and there would be no way to know if it's good or bad at the job. So unless you find another annotated dataset (i.e. a set of resumes with labels indicating whether or not they switched jobs in the past year), you must create your own annotated set.